# How to execute Spark code locally with databricks-connect?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a way to execute Spark code locally with [databricks-connect](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html)?

The reason is that I would like to execute some tests as part of my CI/CD pipeline without the need to have a cluster up and running.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with this for unit-testing mocking spark_session. How you solved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `databricks-connect` requires a running cluster.
If you do not use any databricks specific code (like `dbutils`) you can run spark locally and execute against that - assuming you can still access the data sources you need.

Comment: Sad news as I will need to wait for DDL/DML available in Databricks to be supported in open source Delta Lake. Thanks.