# Switching between Databricks Connect and local Spark environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I am looking to use Databricks Connect for developing a pyspark pipeline. DBConnect is really awesome because I am able to run my code on the cluster where the actual data resides, so it's perfect for integration testing, but I also want to be able to, during development and unit testing (`pytest` with `pytest-spark`), simply using a local Spark environment.

Is there any way to configure DBConnect so for one use-case I simply use a local Spark environment, but for another it uses DBConnect?

Comment: Is 
`sc.stop()`
`conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local")`
`sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)` 
what you're looking for?

Comment: Similarly, `SparkSession.builder.master('local').getOrCreate()` was working with `a new venv`. I used to be in the venv where the databricks-connect package having a pyspark is installed but this was still trying to connect with remote cluster. To resolve it, I'm have two venvs; one for databricks-connect(remote cluster) and one for local cluster

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57186230/877069

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation and this is what I did:

```
use_databricks = os.getenv(MY_ENV_VAR, "dev") == "test"

if use_databricks:
    from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession as SparkSession
else:
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

The above code will check `MY_ENV_VAR` and based on it will load `databricks-connect` library or `pyspark` library. Python doesn't complain if you don't have it installed until you run it, I assume that is one of the benefits that Python is not a precompiled language.

I have also identified that if you have installed both `pyspark` and `databricks-connect` then databricks library is always overriding the main spark with own implementation. Therefore I had to split managing dependencies into two requirements files:

```
# requirements.txt
pyspark==3.5.0
pytest==7.4.3
```

and

```
# requirements-test.txt
-r requirements.txt

databricks-connect==14.0.1
```

When I work locally on my PC I want to run with local spark so I install only `pip install -r requirements.txt`

When I run in CI/CD I want to use databricks cluster and databricks-connect library and therefore there I install with `pip install -r requirements-test.txt` which will also include all dependencies from main `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents, since I've been done this type of development for some months now:

- **Work with two Python environments**: one with databricks-connect (and thus, no pyspark installed), and another one with only pyspark installed. When you want to execute the tests, just activate the "local" virtual environment and run pytest as usual. Make sure, as some commenters pointed out, that you are initializing the pyspark session using `SparkConf().setMaster("local")`.
- **Pycharm** helps immensely to switch between environments during development. I am always on the "local" venv by default, but whenever I want to execute something using databricks-connect, I just create a new Run configuration from the menu. Easy peasy.

Also, be aware of some of databricks-connect's limitations:

- It is not officially supported anymore, and Databricks recommend moving towards [dbx](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html) whenever possible.
- UDFs just won't work in databricks-connect.
- Mlflow integration is not reliable. In my use case, I am able to download and use models, but unable to log a new experiment or track models using `databricks` tracking uri. This might depend on your Databricks Runtime, mlflow and local Python version.

Comment: Switching environments will not work for me. Parts of my code depend on databricks-connect library like this: `from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession`

So if I run an environment without the databricks connect library, then this line is failing my code.

Comment: Yes, that started happening from dbconnect version 13 and higher. Before, you could just start a normal PysparkSession and everything would work, but since version 13 the library requires you to create a DatabricksSession instead. You can always create a function to start the session with a try-catch so that if catches the exception and tries to start the session in a different way